# NodePort service is not externally accessible via `port` number

Tags: kubernetes

I have following service configuration:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: web-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: userapp
    tier: web
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8090
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31000
```

and an nginx container is behind this service. Although I can access to the service via `nodePort`, service is not accessible via `port` field. I'm able to see the configs with `kubectl` and Kubernetes dashboard but `curl`ing to that port (e.g. `curl http://192.168.0.100:8090`) raises a **Connection Refused** error.

I'm not sure what is the problem here. Do I need to make sure any proxy services is running inside the Node or Container?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Get the IP of the kubernetes service and then hit 8090; it will work.
nodePort implies that the service is bound to the node at port 31000.

These are the 3 things that will work:

```
curl <node-ip>:<node-port>        # curl <node-ip>:31000
curl <service-ip>:<service-port>  # curl <svc-ip>:8090
curl <pod-ip>:<target-port>       # curl <pod-ip>:80
```

So now, let's look at 3 situations:

**1. You are inside the kubernetes cluster (you are a pod)**

`<service-ip>` and `<pod-ip>` and `<node-ip>` will work.

**2. You are on the node**

`<service-ip>` and `<pod-ip>` and `<node-ip>` will work.

**3. You are outside the node**

Only `<node-ip>` will work assuming that `<node-ip>` is reachable.

Comment: that makes complete sense to me. I will test this, +1 for the clear explanation.

Comment: hmm, I see `<nodes>` in the external IP column and something like `10.0.0.91` in the cluster IP for that service. What does this mean? (sorry if the question is too basic)

Comment: All of these seemed to just hang for me. I used `kubectl describe service <my-service>` to get the `<service-ip>`. My service has `port` set to `80`, `targetPort` set to `8080`, and `nodePort` set to `31000`. None of those options worked. Is there something else we're supposed to do?

Comment: In case someone is looking for #3 and has the same issue that I did, adding `iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT` on the nodes in question will also help. See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667659/kubernetes-cannot-access-nodeport-from-other-machines)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is as expected since I assume you are trying to access the service from outside the cluster. That means only the `nodePort` exposes the service to the world outside the cluster. The `port` refers to the port on the pod, as exposed by the container inside the pod. This is generally desired behavior as to support clusters of services that are represented by a loadbalancer typically. So the load balancer will expose the port you want for your service (e.g. `load-balancer:80`) and forward to the nodePort on all nodes as to distribute the load.

If you accessing the service from inside the cluster you should be able to reach it via `service-name:service-port` thanks to the built in DNS.

More detailed information can be found at the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).